# OpenGL overlay on camera preview - need to set content views in reverse order?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

I am trying to show a dynamic OpenGL over the Android camera preview. I have used the typical framework suggested in other guides/sites to create an object which implements the GLSurfaceView.Renderer interface and use setContentView() and addContentView() after. The problem is that the onDrawImage is occurring behind the surface holder which displays the camera preview.

This is part of a larger application and I have separately tested all components in a side application. The only difference between the two is that the larger application has several activities preceding this one, while the side application uses just this activity as the main one.

**Update**
The answer is to switch the order of the setContentView and addContentView. If it is the main application, use the order in this post: [opengl overlay on camera view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986437/opengl-overlay-on-camera-view); however, if you are coming from another activity, run:

```
setContentView(theCameraCallbackView)
addContentView(theOpenGLView, new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ))
```

If anyone can provide some reasoning behind this, it would be greatly appreciated! I spend about eight hours on this two-line swap so it would be great to know what the cause of this was (and hopefully prevent similar issues for others).

Comment: weird... I'm having trouble getting this overlay to work and I've tried both orderings on my cameraSurfaceView and my glSurfaceView.